# QGIS: creating a grid over a canvas with 50m by 50m edges

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I know I can overlay a grid on my canvas by going to `view -> decorations -> grid`.

However, I want to overlay a box grid that is 50 by 50 meters. Is there a way to specify this?

```
CRS: WGS 84 zone 47 N
EPSG: 32647
```

It is a map of Thailand.

I looked at [create points at 50m](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263878/create-points-at-50m-intervals-along-line-in-epsg4326) and [creating fishnet grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/creating-fishnet-grid-shapefile-in-qgis).

`SAGA -> vector general -> create polygons`

From creating fishnet grid answer, does division width and division height correspond to meters? Is it capable of being set to a certain unit?

Comment: The unit of `EPSG: 32647` is in meter. What is the problem with it? Look at the details here: https://epsg.io/32647

Comment: @ahmadhanb I am not a GIS expert. I didn't know that. I just want to create a 50 by 50 meter grid overlaying the country. I am simply trying to do that.

Comment: Then use the one of the answers in the question you are referring: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/creating-fishnet-grid-shapefile-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1 to create a grid 50 x 50 m as your EPSG already in meter.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I am trying that so does that mean division height, width set to 50 would be `50x50` meters?

Comment: In QGIS, use `Vector -> Research Tools -> Create Grid`. Set the horizontal and vertical spacing to 50. If you want polygon, select polygon under `Grid type`. Then run the tool.

Comment: @ahmadhanb okay, thanks. I will give that a try.

Comment: @ahmadhanb what is the difference between overlay and spacing?

Comment: Please have a look at the help: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid. If you need to set the grid spacing to 50 for both horizontal and vertical, just use horizontal spacing and vertical spacing, and ignore the overlay (keep the default value). Personally I did not use horizontal and vertical overlay. If you want to see the difference, you can test it with some values and see the results.